# Next.js - Vercel build failed - An unexpected internal error occurred

Tags: deployment, next.js, hosting, server-side-rendering, vercel

we use vercel for hosting our next.js project, which worked properly until now. After a while, I've just deployed my site to vercel which has a lot of pregenerated static pages (FAQ pages localized version ca 7500 sites) (earlier it worked...)

Here is the Build log:

```
[15:22:56.443] Cloning github.com/*** (Branch: main, Commit: 7458f54)
[15:22:57.144] Cloning completed: 701.296ms
[15:22:57.492] Installing build runtime...
[15:23:00.574] Build runtime installed: 3.082s
[15:23:01.366] Looking up build cache...
[15:23:01.611] Build Cache not found
[15:23:01.808] Installing dependencies...
[15:23:01.809] Detected `package-lock.json` generated by npm 7...
[15:23:10.887] npm WARN deprecated urix@0.1.0: Please see https://github.com/lydell/urix#deprecated
[15:23:11.276] npm WARN deprecated source-map-url@0.4.0: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-url#deprecated
[15:23:11.727] npm WARN deprecated request-promise-native@1.0.9: request-promise-native has been deprecated because it extends the now deprecated request package, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
[15:23:11.781] npm WARN deprecated resolve-url@0.2.1: https://github.com/lydell/resolve-url#deprecated
[15:23:12.182] npm WARN deprecated source-map-resolve@0.5.3: See https://github.com/lydell/source-map-resolve#deprecated
[15:23:12.295] npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.1: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
[15:23:12.585] npm WARN deprecated sane@4.1.0: some dependency vulnerabilities fixed, support for node < 10 dropped, and newer ECMAScript syntax/features added
[15:23:14.213] npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
[15:23:14.691] npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
[15:23:14.966] npm WARN deprecated flatten@1.0.3: flatten is deprecated in favor of utility frameworks such as lodash.
[15:23:18.649] npm WARN deprecated querystring@0.2.0: The querystring API is considered Legacy. new code should use the URLSearchParams API instead.
[15:23:19.369] npm WARN deprecated uuid@3.4.0: Please upgrade  to version 7 or higher.  Older versions may use Math.random() in certain circumstances, which is known to be problematic.  See https://v8.dev/blog/math-random for details.
[15:23:22.146] npm WARN deprecated popper.js@1.16.1: You can find the new Popper v2 at @popperjs/core, this package is dedicated to the legacy v1
[15:23:24.656] npm WARN deprecated core-js@1.2.7: core-js@<3.4 is no longer maintained and not recommended for usage due to the number of issues. Because of the V8 engine whims, feature detection in old core-js versions could cause a slowdown up to 100x even if nothing is polyfilled. Please, upgrade your dependencies to the actual version of core-js.
[15:23:31.757] 
[15:23:31.757] added 1284 packages in 30s
[15:23:31.757] 
[15:23:31.758] 123 packages are looking for funding
[15:23:31.758]   run `npm fund` for details
[15:23:31.783] Detected Next.js version: 12.1.0
[15:23:31.796] Detected `package-lock.json` generated by npm 7...
[15:23:31.797] Running "npm run build"
[15:23:32.080] 
[15:23:32.081] > nextjs-builder-io-landing-page@1.0.0 build
[15:23:32.081] > next build
[15:23:32.081] 
[15:23:32.551] info  - Loaded env from /vercel/path0/.env.production
[15:23:32.729] Attention: Next.js now collects completely anonymous telemetry regarding usage.
[15:23:32.729] This information is used to shape Next.js' roadmap and prioritize features.
[15:23:32.729] You can learn more, including how to opt-out if you'd not like to participate in this anonymous program, by visiting the following URL:
[15:23:32.729] https://nextjs.org/telemetry
[15:23:32.729] 
[15:23:32.767] info  - Checking validity of types...
[15:23:36.278] warn  - No ESLint configuration detected. Run next lint to begin setup
[15:23:36.285] info  - Creating an optimized production build...
[15:23:36.286] warn  - using beta Middleware (not covered by semver) - https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/beta-middleware
[15:23:37.976] 
[15:23:37.976] warn - The `purge`/`content` options have changed in Tailwind CSS v3.0.
[15:23:37.976] warn - Update your configuration file to eliminate this warning.
[15:23:58.984] info  - Compiled successfully
[15:23:58.985] info  - Collecting page data...
[15:24:02.966] info  - Generating static pages (0/7848)
[15:24:07.379] info  - Generating static pages (1962/7848)
[15:24:09.446] info  - Generating static pages (3924/7848)
[15:24:11.397] info  - Generating static pages (5886/7848)
[15:24:15.350] info  - Generating static pages (7848/7848)
[15:24:15.367] info  - Finalizing page optimization...
[15:24:17.180] 
[15:24:17.230] Page                                                                                                       Size     First Load JS
[15:24:17.230] ┌ ○ /__builder-customgrid__                                                                                3.8 kB          152 kB
[15:24:17.230] ├ ○ /__builder-customlist__                                                                                2.94 kB         158 kB
[15:24:17.230] ├ ○ /__builder-hero__                                                                                      3.37 kB         152 kB
[15:24:17.231] ├ ○ /__builder-money__                                                                                     1.32 kB         153 kB
[15:24:17.231] ├ ○ /__builder-nav__                                                                                       2.29 kB         167 kB
[15:24:17.231] ├ ○ /__builder-subtab__                                                                                    2.76 kB         141 kB
[15:24:17.231] ├ ○ /__builder-tabcontent__                                                                                4.95 kB         153 kB
[15:24:17.231] ├   /_app                                                                                                  0 B             129 kB
[15:24:17.231] ├ ƒ /_middleware                                                                                           36.4 kB         166 kB
[15:24:17.231] ├ ● /[[...page]]                                                                                           138 kB          313 kB
[15:24:17.231] ├   └ css/f63802154ef558ff.css                                                                             1.21 kB
[15:24:17.231] ├ ○ /404                                                                                                   2.47 kB         141 kB
[15:24:17.231] ├ ○ /500                                                                                                   2.39 kB         141 kB
[15:24:17.231] ├ λ /api/sitemap                                                                                           0 B             129 kB
[15:24:17.231] ├ λ /blog                                                                                                  2.45 kB         161 kB
[15:24:17.231] ├ ● /blog/[article] (ISR: 5 Seconds) (4886 ms)                                                             790 B           159 kB
[15:24:17.231] ├   ├ /default/blog/%2Fblog%2Fblog5 (581 ms)
[15:24:17.231] ├   ├ /default/blog/%2Fblog%2Fblog2-is-lehet (554 ms)
[15:24:17.231] ├   ├ /default/blog/%2Fblog%2Fblog6 (551 ms)
[15:24:17.231] ├   ├ /default/blog/%2Fblog%2Fblog-3-url (547 ms)
[15:24:17.231] ├   ├ /default/blog/%2Fblog%2Fblog-8-english (544 ms)
[15:24:17.232] ├   ├ /default/blog/%2Fblog%2Fblog4 (542 ms)
[15:24:17.232] ├   ├ /default/blog/%2Fblog%2Fblog7 (529 ms)
[15:24:17.232] ├   └ [+2 more paths] (avg 519 ms)
[15:24:17.232] ├ ○ /builder-symbol                                                                                        351 B           172 kB
[15:24:17.232] ├ ● /help/[maincategory] (1386 ms)                                                                         4.07 kB         162 kB
[15:24:17.232] ├   ├ /default/help/how-can-i-get-a-wallet
[15:24:17.232] ├   ├ /default/help/how-much-does-it-cost-to-register-a-new-wallet
[15:24:17.232] ├   ├ /default/help/what-is-the-difference-between-a-personal-and-a-business-wallet
[15:24:17.232] ├   └ [+340 more paths]
[15:24:17.232] ├ ● /help/[maincategory]/[subcategory] (447 ms)                                                            4.3 kB          165 kB
[15:24:17.232] ├   ├ /default/help/business/how-can-i-get-a-wallet
[15:24:17.232] ├   ├ /default/help/business/send-money
[15:24:17.232] ├   ├ /default/help/business/receive-money
[15:24:17.232] ├   └ [+110 more paths]
[15:24:17.232] ├ ● /help/[maincategory]/[subcategory]/[help] (20710 ms)                                                   3.87 kB         162 kB
[15:24:17.232] ├   ├ /default/help/business/how-can-i-get-a-wallet/what-is-identification-and-why-is-it-necessary
[15:24:17.232] ├   ├ /default/help/business/how-can-i-get-a-wallet/how-are-individuals-identified
[15:24:17.232] ├   ├ /default/help/business/how-can-i-get-a-wallet/how-can-i-top-up-my-wallet
[15:24:17.232] ├   └ [+7272 more paths]
[15:24:17.233] ├ ● /integrations-and-plugins                                                                              3.11 kB         161 kB
[15:24:17.233] └ ● /integrations-and-plugins/[id]                                                                         1.46 kB         160 kB
[15:24:17.233] + First Load JS shared by all                                                                              129 kB
[15:24:17.233]   ├ chunks/framework-5f4595e5518b5600.js                                                                   42 kB
[15:24:17.233]   ├ chunks/main-30b5b660246d0905.js                                                                        32.6 kB
[15:24:17.233]   ├ chunks/pages/_app-ad24afc8f8ad930a.js                                                                  52.8 kB
[15:24:17.233]   ├ chunks/webpack-dd16877f2d410294.js                                                                     1.9 kB
[15:24:17.233]   └ css/84deb26cd7ef277b.css                                                                               10.5 kB
[15:24:17.234] 
[15:24:17.234] ƒ  (Middleware)  intercepts requests (uses _middleware)
[15:24:17.234] λ  (Server)      server-side renders at runtime (uses getInitialProps or getServerSideProps)
[15:24:17.234] ○  (Static)      automatically rendered as static HTML (uses no initial props)
[15:24:17.235] ●  (SSG)         automatically generated as static HTML + JSON (uses getStaticProps)
[15:24:17.235]    (ISR)         incremental static regeneration (uses revalidate in getStaticProps)
[15:24:17.235] 
[15:24:20.013] Traced Next.js server files in: 268.788ms
[15:24:20.666] Created all serverless functions in: 652.943ms
[15:24:23.997] Uploading build outputs...
[15:26:55.132] Deploying build outputs...
[15:53:13.710] An unexpected internal error occurred
```

[image]

I contacted the support, but no answer yet, and also saw a github thread 2 weeks ago:
https://github.com/vercel/community/discussions/436

Any idea how can I solve this?

Anyways, I tried with the FAQ page fallback option set to true, false, blocking, none of them seems to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Your build is crashed for no visible reasons - try to reduce build time.***

*Once I have contacted Vercel support (support@vercel.com) for mostly the same issues, they investigated my reasons, but they mostly recommend me to reduce build time (<30 mins it's ok)*

You need to set your pages with [ISR](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/incremental-static-regeneration).

ISR does **not mean that all your pages will be rendered during build**, it means if your page wasn't rendered during the build and will be stored in cache once visited

**Example**: imagine you have 15999 categories to build. Max build time is 45 mins according [to vercel docs](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/limits/overview#general-limits). You should build only part of information during build (500 categories). So, in getStaticPaths, you need to get only 500 categories and make it "lightweight" - include only your parameter (in my example its' pid)

Try to adapt all your pages to reduce build time. Also, don't forget about [Vercel API limits](https://vercel.com/support/articles/how-to-bypass-vercel-5mb-body-size-limit-serverless-functions).

*Here is my example*:

```
export async function getStaticProps(context) {
    const pid = context.params.pid;
    if (context.params.pid == 'undefined'){
        console.log("here we have an error: " + pid)
    }
    //you render your category
    const res = await fetch(process.env.APIpath + '/api/public/category/getCategory?pid=' + (pid));
    const data = await res.json();
    return {
        props: {
            ...(await serverSideTranslations(context.locale, ['common'])),
            category: data
        }
    }
}   
    
export async function getStaticPaths(context) {
    // you render only 500 products intead of 15666 products
    const res = await fetch(process.env.APIpath + '/api/public/category/getFewCategories')
    const posts = await res.json()
  
    let paths = []
    for (const post of posts){
        //I am using multilanguage here
        for (const locale of context.locales){
            paths.push({params: {pid: post.linkRewrite[locale] }, locale: locale})
        }
    }
    
    return { paths, fallback: 'blocking'}
  }
```

Comment: about how many static pages should I prerender and have on vercel?

Comment: because with 8000 pages build failed, but with 5000 it succeeds

Comment: I am rendering about 2000-3000 during build (average 20 mins to build)

Answer (score 0):

I just restarted the build 24h later, and everything worked ok.
I guess sometimes it is just a problem with Vercel itself.